# How to add edges and vertices for given data?

Tags: python, igraph

I have the following data with details:

```
Label= [360, 180, 540, 180, 180, 360, 360, 180, 540, 180, 180, 360]
mean_values= [(270,630), (540,720),(270,810),(450,630),(180,360), (180,540),(450,810),(360,540),(180,720),(630,810),(270,450),(360,720)]
```

I have written the following codes

```
  from igraph import *
        
        g=Graph()
        g.add_vertices(8)
        print(g)
        
        g.add_edges([Edges])
```

Based on my understanding labels can represent vertices (8) and  mean_values can be called edges (12).

With regards to data: Label basically represented by the blue and yellow circles values while means values correspond to which one is related to which label. So for example, among 180,360,540 and 720 label values, 180 connected to 360,540, 720 as seen by arrows and represented by following means values: [(180,360), (180,540),(180,720)] and the similar result can be found with other labels,

Any idea of how to get such a result using igraph. I did a couple of searches but did not get any idea.  I am new to igraph, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
Also, please see the available documentation and examples on `networkx`.  You need to follow the defined interfaces for the package methods.

Comment: I don’t understand how your input data is supposed to correspond to the figure you’ve added. Please double-check your input and add an explanation as necessary.

Comment: I explain this with example. Please do have a look at the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over your vertices and edges:

```
for vertex in vertices:
    g.add_vertex(vertex)

g.add_edges(edges)
```

However, this requires *string names* instead of numeric IDs.

Comment: Hi. I am getting the following error when I ran your code. 'Error at d:\bld\python-igraph_1588168334861\work\vendor\build\igraph\igraph-0.9.0-pre+-msvc\src\type_indexededgelist.c:269: cannot add edges, Invalid vertex id'

Comment: @Ravi See update. But also your example won’t work since your edges use nonexistent vertices, and your vertices contain duplicate IDs.

Comment: I modified my question and also explain what I want. Could you please do have a look and advice me ?